# Newbie Transferring Data 3041

Tags: ms-access

I've been tasked with transferring our information out of an old antiquated system, back into Access.
I have personally not used Access before, and I'm seeing that in order to transfer the data, I have to compact the file, because the data set was created on an older version of Access.

After hours of trying to find a function to do this that actually works, it seems like I can't find anything that works. Has anyone had success in this?

I'm wondering if it's easier to have two data sets, one in excel that is searchable for the old data set, and create a new database for all new items in Access, and anything that needs to be changed from the old database, could be transferred on a "as needed" basis.

We track Serial Numbers, Warranty & Purchase dates, Purchase Order Numbers, along with customer names. So it's not a large amount of information, however it needs to be clear and efficient.

Any wise words greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the old file an Access .mdb? What do you mean by 'compact the file'?

Comment: If you have access to the old database try exporting the data to either an excell file or a text file.  Then import the new file into the newer version of access.  If the old database is large try exporting it in pieces.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It is a .mdb file. The error code, 3041 exclaims that it is compact. I have already tried exporting to both excel and text, without any success!